# 物体検出したときに画像を保存したいが、グレースケールのままになる

Tags: python, opencv

ssd_kerasのサンプルコードssd.ipynbです。
猫を検出した時だけ、ファイルCatに保存したいのですが、
グレースケールのまま保存されてしまいます。

```
import cv2
import keras
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import tensorflow as tf

from ssd import SSD300
from ssd_utils import BBoxUtility

%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 8)
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.45
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))

voc_classes = ['Aeroplane', 'Bicycle', 'Bird', 'Boat', 'Bottle',
               'Bus', 'Car', 'Cat', 'Chair', 'Cow', 'Diningtable',
               'Dog', 'Horse','Motorbike', 'Person', 'Pottedplant',
               'Sheep', 'Sofa', 'Train', 'Tvmonitor']
NUM_CLASSES = len(voc_classes) + 1

input_shape=(300, 300, 3)
model = SSD300(input_shape, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
model.load_weights('weights_SSD300.hdf5', by_name=True)
bbox_util = BBoxUtility(NUM_CLASSES)

inputs = []
images = []
img_path = './pics/fish-bike.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
images.append(imread(img_path))
inputs.append(img.copy())
img_path = './pics/cat.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
images.append(imread(img_path))
inputs.append(img.copy())
img_path = './pics/boys.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
images.append(imread(img_path))
inputs.append(img.copy())
img_path = './pics/car_cat.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
images.append(imread(img_path))
inputs.append(img.copy())
img_path = './pics/car_cat2.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
images.append(imread(img_path))
inputs.append(img.copy())
inputs = preprocess_input(np.array(inputs))

preds = model.predict(inputs, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

results = bbox_util.detection_out(preds)

%%time
a = model.predict(inputs, batch_size=1)
b = bbox_util.detection_out(preds)

for i, img in enumerate(images):
    # Parse the outputs.
    det_label = results[i][:, 0]
    det_conf = results[i][:, 1]
    det_xmin = results[i][:, 2]
    det_ymin = results[i][:, 3]
    det_xmax = results[i][:, 4]
    det_ymax = results[i][:, 5]

    # Get detections with confidence higher than 0.6.
    top_indices = [i for i, conf in enumerate(det_conf) if conf >= 0.6]

    top_conf = det_conf[top_indices]
    top_label_indices = det_label[top_indices].tolist()
    top_xmin = det_xmin[top_indices]
    top_ymin = det_ymin[top_indices]
    top_xmax = det_xmax[top_indices]
    top_ymax = det_ymax[top_indices]

    colors = plt.cm.hsv(np.linspace(0, 1, 21)).tolist()

    plt.imshow(img / 255.)
    currentAxis = plt.gca()

　　cat_count = 0
    for i in range(top_conf.shape[0]):
        xmin = int(round(top_xmin[i] * img.shape[1]))
        ymin = int(round(top_ymin[i] * img.shape[0]))
        xmax = int(round(top_xmax[i] * img.shape[1]))
        ymax = int(round(top_ymax[i] * img.shape[0]))
        score = top_conf[i]
        label = int(top_label_indices[i])
        label_name = voc_classes[label - 1]
        display_txt = '{:0.2f}, {}'.format(score, label_name)
        coords = (xmin, ymin), xmax-xmin+1, ymax-ymin+1
        color = colors[label]
        currentAxis.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(*coords, fill=False, edgecolor=color, linewidth=2))
        currentAxis.text(xmin, ymin, display_txt, bbox={'facecolor':color, 'alpha':0.5})
    cat_count += label_name.count('Cat')

    plt.show()

    if cat_count == 1:
        cv2.imwrite('./Cat/''cat'+str(i)+'.jpg', img)
```

Comment: もしかして、これ [matplotlibのimshowは勝手に正規化する話](http://hikuichi.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/26/225623) あたり関係して無いですかね？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 画像の読み込み => `scipy.misc.imread` : RGB (赤緑青)
- 画像の書き出し => `cv2.imwrite` : BGR（青緑赤）

とモジュールごとに色素空間の扱いが異なることから、opencvがBとRを逆にして画像を保存していることが原因です。
RGBからBGRに画像を変換してから保存すると大丈夫です。

```
if cat_count == 1:
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # RGBからBGRに変換する
    cv2.imwrite('./Cat/''cat'+str(i)+'.jpg', img)
```

参考：
http://lang.sist.chukyo-u.ac.jp/classes/OpenCV/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html
（一番最後のWarning欄）

---

補足

この画像をscipy.misc.imreadで読んだ状態

[image: 最初の画像]

上の状態でcv2.imwriteを使ってそのまま書き出した状態

[image: cv2.imwriteした画像]

cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)で変換してから書き出した状態

[image: 変換後]

Comment: できました！ありがとうございました！